# Rep gain through edits alone?

Tags: discussion

After noticing a lot of old questions getting dragged back to the front page I looked into why  - They've all been edited to fix broken links pointing to a single domain. I then got curious about the person doing the editing (they must have been approved by someone else because the user has only 33 rep).

One rather remarkable thing stood out on [that user's profile page](https://serverfault.com/users/119685/user1204270). Namely, that he has been getting 2 rep for posts where his only input was an edit. When did rep start being handed out for edits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rep started getting handed out for edits at the same time that the edit queue was introduced for users without full edit rights.

As for the rest, I approved them because they seemed to be legitimate. SE is now flagging questions with broken links, and these would have eventually been caught up with by the script I'm guessing.

Comment: They were good edits. Just the quantity attracted my attention, which then made me curious about the person behind them. No complaints. Just puzzled about the rep.

Answer (score 2):

The February 2011 edition of [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) notes on 02-02-2011 that [this mSO Request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep) has been implemented.

Comment: OK, I'll put t down to yet another unannounced change to the way the site works. It seems we're expected to scour MSO regularly just to find out what's getting changed here. Am I the only one who sees the wrongness of that?

Comment: Yes, the 'documentation' leaves a lot to be desired ;) I jus scan the first link I gave every now and then then to see if anything major has happened.